# After uninstalling EHCP, how do I get my original postfix configuration back?

Tags: postfix

I tried installing EHCP recently, which was a disaster because it's not optimized for keeping your database on a separate machine from the mail server--"localhost" is hard-coded just about everywhere.

After following [these deceptively simple directions](http://www.ehcp.net/?q=node/46) for uninstalling EHCP, I cannot send mail because my postfix installation was heavily reconfigured by EHCP's installation script.

What are the steps in fixing my postfix configuration, assuming I did not make a backup of my postfix directory before attempting to install?

Comment: It might be worth checking if the install left the original files intact in `/etc/postfix`, otherwise simply restore from backup.

Comment: Could someone with 300 points please tag this question "ehcp"

Answer (score 1):

Restoring them from a backup, naturally, or from your configuration repository like `etckeeper` or your config management system.

If you don't have any of those, you'll end up doing your configuration work again.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying this, I made /etc/postfix a git repo and made a commit of the current (post-EHCP) state.

1. In /etc/postfix, I deleted the following files:

   (git) rm -r cacert.pem cakey.pem mysql-virtual_* sasl/ smtpd.cert smtpd.key

That left only the following files remaining:

```
access
canonical
generic
header_checks
main.cf
master.cf
relocated
transport
virtual
```

2. I removed the following lines from configuration:

In master.cf:

```
ehcp_autoreply unix - n n - - pipe
  user=vmail
  argv=/var/www/ehcp/misc/autoreply.php $sender $recipient
```

In main.cf:

```
myhostname = ip-[FILTERED IP ADDRESS]
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/16, 10.0.0.0/8,  172.16.1.0/24
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
debug_peer_list = 
sender_canonical_maps =
```

I also removed from main.cf every line containing 'mysql', 'smtpd' or 'virtual'

3. I made the following changes in main.cf:

   I changed the line beginning with "mydestination = " to:
     mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost

   I uncommented the line "mynetworks style = hosts"

   I changed "debug_peer_level" from 1 to 2 (I don't think this part was really necessary).